# How to check if String contains only operators and numbers in as3?

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3

How to check if String contains only operators and numbers.

The string which may contains 0-9 and +,-,.,/,*,X,=

For example : 28+30-22*5 = when i check this it should return true. If this contains a character then it will return false.

Can we use regexp for this.

Comment: try `[0-9+-./*X=]*`.

Comment: @GuoranYun you may want the second `-` to appear at one end, otherwise it may be treated as a range (in ASCII, `+-.` matches `+`, `,`, `-` ,`.` ).

Comment: @Jhnc Point taken. The `-` should  appear at the end of character range. like `[0-9+./*X=-]*`

Comment: What about incorrect expression, like "+-+20\*\*"?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally primitive and straightforward, but it should do the trick:

```
// A collection of valid characters.
const VALID:String = "0123456789+-*/=X ";

function check(sample:String):Boolean
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < sample.length; i++)
    {
        // Let's iterate the given String, char by char.
        var aChar:String = sample.charAt(i);
        
        // The .indexOf(...) method returns -1 if there's no match.
        if (sample.indexOf(aChar) < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    // If we got as far as here, it means
    // there's no invalid characters in the sample.
    return true;
}

trace(check("28+30-22*5 =")); // true
trace(check("a = 100 * 3 / 10")); // false
```

Of course you can do it the **RegExp** way, but it will probably be the same logic, just less readable, more difficult to handle, and not measurably faster.